# Alternative to Unit of Work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am working on creating ASP.net MVC project which would use stored procedures to insert/update data.
Currently am using repository pattern with Unit of work.
But since UnitOfWork.Commit would never be called, won't Unit of Work be redundant?

If so, what would be a better architecture to follow?

Answer (score 0):

The repository is the important bit - it keeps all database-access code in one place.

Stick with what you're doing and ignore the UOW facility which you do not need at the moment (but maybe you will need it later).

Comment: Isn't there any alternative architecture which doesn't use UoW?

Comment: Of course. Just use a repository without it. What's the problem?

Comment: Would using Dapper instead of EF help?

Comment: Yes, or you could use EF. Just use the features you need, ignore the rest. it's just software, not a religion.